# Unable to see DBMS_OUTPUT in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, dbms-output

I am using Oracle Sql Developer (Version 18.4.0.376).
In Sql editor all DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE are not disabled automatically.
Please refer the below screen shots
Can any one suggest me, How to get ride this issue.
[image]

[image]

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for edit this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database is too old.

10g database and the jdbc driver we use from 2019 won't play nice for getting dbms output.

You're using xe - get a newer one, either 11g or 18c. Both are still free.

Answer (score 0):

- Install the latest database like 18 or 19c
- Establish the oracle connection with user credentials
- Open the sql editor and execute the sample pl/sql procedure
- Choose the dbms output window from views menu and set the buffer size as you required.

[image]